# Pass column name to a function

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test123(column_name VARCHAR(40)) RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE   
    rec RECORD ;
BEGIN
    SELECT * INTO rec FROM my_table WHERE column_name=1 LIMIT 1;
    RETURN rec;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How can you pass the column name to a function and then use that name in the query?

The above code does not work:

```
error: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
```

Comment: You need dynamic SQL for that. See the manual for some examples: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you want to use function parameters as *identifiers* in queries inside a function you need to dynamically `EXECUTE` the query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test123(column_name VARCHAR(40)) RETURNS RECORD AS $$
DECLARE   
    rec RECORD;
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE %I = 1 LIMIT 1', column_name)
    INTO rec;
    RETURN rec;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

or much shorter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test123(column_name VARCHAR(40)) RETURNS RECORD AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE %I = 1 LIMIT 1', column_name);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```